# Describe the machine and service infrastructure with a diagram

Tags: virtualization, infrastructure

We have a provider that manages a Baremetal server where there are many VPSs inside and each VPS manages some services.

We would like to have the infrastructure described in terms of machines (servers, disks, etc.), services and communications, so as to facilitate a possible change of supplier in understanding the system.

Are there any standards in this regard?

Comment: Can you give a bit more clarity, I don't seem to understand what you need as an answer. You are looking for a way to describe that infrastructure, like a software that does that or some practices how to describe it? For example in the past, I have done diagrams for the base infrastructure and connection between services and another file with a list of all the components, sizes, and prices. But there are other ways as well.

Comment: @kristian-kanchev, not a software, but a way, if there is a standard or recommended ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on my comment, I can only share my personal experience and what worked with our clients in the past.

1. You have to have a Diagram with an at least high overview on how the services will work: Example Client>Internet>Load Balancer>EC2>Web Server>Database and etc. There are many programs that you can use for that, example draw.io or Lucidchart(I prefer Lucidchart for the UI and it has a free option).
2. Some price ranges and estimations, the simplest way I used was make an estimation in Azure Calculator and export it in CSV. Make some highlights that you think are important to know and any additional calculations based on your services(for example what they pay you for XX of time work for 1 year).
3. Make a few estimations. What we did as an estimation thats for the best price, but does not ensure the best performance(basically based on the app and load the Minimum Requirements). And an estimation for best performance, where the price is high but you know thats going to hold a lot of load.

These are 3 major components IMO. We also used a detailed list of the services we provided and "plan" type which you can use. For example plan 1 includes 1 service, plan 2 includes 5 and etc(basically like a subscription).

I am explaining it like Im the one providing you a service and letting you know what you will get. In your specific case, you can ask all the above => Prices for each component and Server size, disk size and etc. Where all the connection goes, the list of VM/Servers and their specifications. What is used for what and so on.

In a few words, the best practices is to know what you are paying for and how it is being used. In what details you want that is fully up to you. And you as a client should have the full right to do that. If you wanted from me for example to see how much traffic you get, I would give you that with no problems.